# Почему WP_Query paged возвращает 1 для всех страниц?

Tags: php, wordpress

Делаю шаблон страницы результатов поиска search.php

И столкнулся с проблемой. Не работает пагинация.
А именно, как я понимаю, не определяется номер текущей страницы.
WP_Query paged всегда равно 1.

При приклике на пагинацию, ссылка формируется вроде правильно ( /page/2/?s=поисковой запрос )
но записи не меняются.

Вот мой код:

```
<?php



    $thesearch = get_search_query(); 
    

    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
                's' => $thesearch,
                'posts_per_page' => 20,
                'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id',
                  array(
                    'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
                    'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                  ),
        
                'paged' => $paged
            );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


?>
                      

                        
<?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
```

Пагинация стандартная the_posts_pagination(  );

Comment: Потому что если посмотреть в код функции `the_posts_pagination();` (обертка для `get_the_posts_pagination()`), то она работает с глобальной переменной `$wp_query` и о Вашем `$the_query` ничего не знает.

Comment: с глобальной $wp_query тоже не работает